# Azure web-sites private packages source

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-web-app-service

On my project I need to use private packages.
Does azure web sites support publishing project using private packages via npm  or other source?

Answer (score 2):

We support npm from private git repo.   See [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1044).  However, you will have to set up ssh keys (See [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#for-private-repos-set-up-a-deploy-key)).  Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you plan some extended and simple support of this?